# Error at SQL PostExecute to SSISPckgLog [Execute SQL Task]: Connection manager "" does not exist

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I'm new to SSIS (but I have experience with c# .NET, SSRS, TSQL, and so on). I was handed an old SSIS package and have successfully upgraded it to work in Visual Studio 2013, SQL Server 2014, with project deployment model. Next I want to use project level connection managers. I created a new one and changed all the connections in one of my packages to use it. Then I deleted the old (package level) connection manager and started getting this error: Error at SQL PostExecute to SSISPckgLog [Execute SQL Task]: Connection manager "oldConnection" does not exist. Can someone help me find where PostExecute is located. It is not visible on the Control Flow surface. If I can find it, I can change it so it will use my new project level connection manager. Thanks in advance!
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh. Good to know. Thanks. Do you think that is the cause of this issue?

Comment: Ha! I double checked and I am using SQL Server 2014. I will edit the question.

Comment: Oh, do you still have Logging to SQL Server turned on? If memory serves, that doesn't know how to use a Project Level Connection manager. If so, disable that. The project deployment model has logging built in

Comment: That sounds promising. How do I turn Logging off?

Comment: You've certainly come up with a fun one. Can you post a screen shot of what the package looks like at the control flow level. Make sure the "Error List" is visible please. In your Output window (Ctrl-Alt-O), grab all the lines that start with ERROR (should be about 3)

Comment: I added pictures. The build has no errors, but there is a run-time error (the one I'm asking about). The package I'm working with first is 00_LoadSfmsProfileTables.

Comment: Oh wow, you have my condolences on that package. At this point, I'd probably right click on the package and View Code. Search for the guid 81df... and then try to figure out what's referencing it. Is that 00 package being called from another package?

Comment: Each package is stand-alone. My task is to upgrade and write the logic to call each package when it is appropriate (based on a truly complex schedule). Thanks for the condolences. :) I will try View Code.

Answer (score 3):

The little used tab called Package Explorer will be your friend in this situation. There, you'll get a tree like view of the package. Look through the Event Handlers and Executables (as they could be on specific executables)

[image]

Based on comments, you might also have logging turned on. To disable, right click in the background of the control flow (or go to the SSIS menu) and select Logging. Delete the any that have an empty value in Configuration

[image]

Keeping this here because it bites a lot of people.

Originally, it was stated that the problem domain contained VS 2013 and SQL Server 2012. The problem you're going to run into is a mismatch between SQL Server and its Integration Services and your Visual Studio version.

- VS 2012 targets SQL Server 2012
- VS 2013 targets SQL Server 2014

You can always move up (2012 packages will run on 2014) but the downgrading of packages is not a capability of ... pretty much any MS product

Comment: Thanks billinkc. Unfortunately it's not showing up in executables nor in event handlers. I have a lot of executables but none of them resemble SQL PostExecute to SSISPckgLog. I have only one Event handler: OnError.

Comment: SQL Server 2012 was a bug in the question. I actually have 2014.

Comment: Too bad. That doesn't seem to be the problem. I don't have any logging turned on. There's nothing to delete. It was a good thought, though.

Comment: I have not figured it out yet, but I did find a work-around. I reverted to a version of my project from source control that still contained the package level connection manager I was trying to remove. Then, instead of deleting the connection manager (package level) and adding a new (project level) connection, I promoted the old one to a project level connection manager. This way all references to it were still pointing to it. I also renamed it and that worked fine.

Comment: There may be trouble ahead as I try to make all the packages connections point to the same project level connection managers.